# Receiving Javascript Error on Click of a button

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Please find below the  code of Button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")} 


var callout = sforce.apex.execute(
     "AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl",
    "exportToExcel",
    {param:"{!FldUtl__Object_Analysis__c.Id}"}); 

if (callout == 'OK') { 
    alert("Your Request is Successful. Click OK and please wait while the page refreshes"); 
    window.location.reload(); 
} 
else { 
    alert("Request Failed " + callout ); 
}
```

**Onclick of a button** below error in the Image is fired.... Please Help!!!

[image]

Comment: If the below answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you don't have a AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl.exportToExcel method...

If you do, check that it is declared as `Webservice Static String`.

If you have a namespace for this class, you shoud call like this

```
var callout = sforce.apex.execute(
"YourNamespace.AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl",
"exportToExcel",
{param:"{!FldUtl__Object_Analysis__c.Id}"});
```

Comment: @Rajesh When you get a moment, please check the `✓` on the answer so it can help others find this solution.